# Hyperlink jumping to incorrect location for \newtcolorbox labeling in compilation LaTeX -> dvi -> ps -> pdf

Tags: hyperref, tcolorbox, cleveref

By compiling the following sample code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[dvips,colorlinks,bookmarks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage{longfbox}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter,crefname={theorem}{theorems}]{theo}[2][]{%
breakable,enhanced,colback=blue!5!white,
colframe=blue!75!black,
colbacktitle=cyan!50!green,
coltitle=blue!25!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
subtitle style={boxrule=0.4pt,colback=cyan!50!red!25!white},title=Theorem~\thetcbcounter~#2,#1}

\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}

\begin{document}

\begin{proposition}\label{pro:1}
Proposition!
\end{proposition}


\begin{theo}[label=mytheo]{(My Theorem)}
\lipsum
\end{theo}

My \Cref{mytheo} and my \Cref{pro:1}.

\end{document}
```

as LaTeX -> dvi -> ps -> pdf, the link for "Theorem 0.1" jumps to the bottom of the page. On the other hand, the link for "Proposition 1" works perfectly. By compiling the code directly as PDFLaTeX (removing `dvips` on `hyperref` package), this problem disappears. I'm trying to understand why this happen, but until now, unsuccessfully. Moreover, as suggested, I used `\phantomsection` and does not work; indeed, a similar problem has occurred with links for sections and `\phantomsection` worked fine. However, I wasn't successful to using it in current situation. Of course, I also tried compiling the file as XeLaTeX, but the obtained final pdf output version is not exactly the same as the pdf output generated by dvi -> ps -> pdf (namely, some bolds on cover page title strangely appears on XeLaTeX output). Since this problem don't occur for \newtheorem, I presume that this is possibly related with \newtcolorbox.

I need to compile the file as LaTeX -> dvi -> ps -> pdf (I have several eps figures and files). How can I solve this, i.e. how can I put the links jumping to the right place in LaTeX -> dvi -> ps -> pdf compilation? Any help is welcome. Thanks, C.W.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the time to debug this now, but basically it is a tikz problem. If you compile the following with pdflatex
then the destination created by the \phantomsection is

```
/D [5 0 R /XYZ 148.912 674.665 null]
```

That is a position more or less at the top of the page (pdf measures from the bottom, so 674.665 is quite high.)

With latex +dvips you get a much lower position:

```
<</D [4 0 R /XYZ 170.407654 250.006836 null]>>endobj
```

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz,hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red](0,0) rectangle (10,15);
\path[use as bounding box](0,0) rectangle (10,15);
\pgftext[x=0pt,y=15cm,right,top]{xxxx\phantomsection\label{blub}};%
\end{tikzpicture}

\pageref{blub}

\end{document}
```

You can make a bug report but I'm not sure that this can be easily resolved. I would suggest to try to use pdflatex instead. It can handle eps files or you could convert them first to pdf.